# not able to read data when tag is scanned and app is not visible

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I am trying to create a sample to read and write data to NFC Tag.
I am writing data to the NFC tag with an AAR and other timestamp info as follows:

```
Message message = new Message();
AndroidApplicationRecord aar = new AndroidApplicationRecord(AAR);
message.add(aar);

TextRecord textRecord = new TextRecord(String.valueOf(currServiceDate));
message.add(textRecord);
```

Now if I go out of the app and scan the NFC tag, my activity gets launched due to the AAR entry but I am not able to read the NDEF message. To read the NDEF message I have to scan the NFC tag again and only after that I am able to view the stored data on the tag.

**my onResume code:**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        Log.e(TAG , "detect message");   
    }

    enableForegroundMode();
}

public void enableForegroundMode() {
    if (nfcAdapter != null) {
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED); // filter for all
        IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED); // filter for all

        IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] {tagDetected, ndefDetected};
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not supported on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**code inside onCreate**:

```
public void readTagIntent() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Log.i(TAG + " EXTRA_TAG called ", currentTagId+" "+intent.getAction());

    if(intent != null) {     
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
                currentTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                currentTagId = SenseMeUtils.toHexString(currentTag.getId());

                Log.i(TAG + " EXTRA_TAG readTagIntent ", currentTagId+"");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. what you want actually?

Comment: when i scan a tag , my activity gets load successfully , but i am not be able to read  the data within the tag

Comment: make `enableForegroundMode();` and then Your if condition. in `onResume();`